# .NET Regular Expressions: get second batch of numerals

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, numeric

I'm having a problem on my `RegEx`. I want to get the second batch of numbers only.

**>> Sample Text:**

```
[xxx] 20 xxxx XXX [0.500 yyy] 
[xxx] 20 xxxx XXX [2.000 ]
```

**>> Sample RegEx:**

```
[[0-9.]+(?:[Ee][0-9.]*)?[DdFf]?]
```

But I'm getting this result:

[image]

I just want the 2nd batch numbers `(0.500 & 2.000)` only.

Where did I go wrong?

Any alternative solutions is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below lookahead based regex.

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\D*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that is based on the position of the number before a `[`:

```
(?<=\[)[0-9.]+
```

Or, if you want to allow just 1 dot:

```
(?<=\[)[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B)%5B0-9%5D%2B(.%5B0-9%5D%2B)%3F&i=%5Bxxx%5D%2020%20xxxx%20XXX%20%5B0.500%20yyy%5D%20%0D%0A%5Bxxx%5D%2020%20xxxx%20XXX%20%5B2.000%20%5D)

In C#,

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(@"(?<=\[)[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Be careful with `\d` in .NET, it may also match [`٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b&i=%d9%a0%d9%a1%d9%a2%d9%a3%d9%a4%d9%a5%d9%a6%d9%a7%d9%a8%d9%a9), but I think you are not targeting it to the Arabic audience :)